# Piton and Pyluatex environments : write the content to an external file

Tags: python, pyluatex, piton

I have a few environments for Python created from `piton` package on the one hand, and `Pyluatex` on the other.

Sometimes I'd like to copy their contents into an external python file (which is then created if it doesn't already exist). Do you know how this could be done? For example, by creating an optional argument to the environments created? A star version of `pyverbatim*`, `pyblock*` etc ?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,currfile,needspace,fontawesome5,luacode}
\usepackage{pyluatex}
\usepackage{piton}

\begin{luacode}
function pytypeset()
    tex.print("\\begin{Piton}")
    tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_code())
    tex.print("\\end{Piton}")
    tex.print("")
end

function pytypesetREPL()
    tex.print("\\begin{Piton}")
    tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_output())
    tex.print("\\end{Piton}")
    tex.print("")
end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand*{\pytypeset}
    {\directlua{pytypeset()}}
\newcommand*{\pytypesetREPL}
    {\directlua{pytypesetREPL()}}

% Environnements Python
\NewPitonEnvironment{pyverbatim}{ !d<> !O{} }{
    \Needspace*{\baselineskip}
    \IfValueT{#1}{{\bfseries\sffamily\color{mongris}{\tiny\faSquare\:\faSquare\:\:}#1}}
    \PitonOptions{#2}}{}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{pyconsole}{ !d<> !O{} }
    {\Needspace*{\baselineskip}\PyLTVerbatimEnv\begin{pythonrepl}}
    {\end{pythonrepl}
    \IfValueT{#1}{{\bfseries\sffamily{\tiny\faSquare\:\faSquare\:\:}#1}}
    \PitonOptions{#2}\pytypesetREPL}
%
\newenvironment{pycode}
    {\PyLTVerbatimEnv\begin{pythonq}}
    {\end{pythonq}}
%
\NewDocumentEnvironment{pyblock}{ !d<> !O{} } 
    {\PyLTVerbatimEnv\begin{pythonq}}
    {\end{pythonq}
    \Needspace*{\baselineskip}
    \IfValueT{#1}{{\bfseries\sffamily{\tiny\faSquare\:\faSquare\:\:}#1}}
    \PitonOptions{#2}\pytypeset
    \Needspace*{\baselineskip}
    }
%
\begin{document}

\begin{pyverbatim}
x = 1   
\end{pyverbatim}

\begin{pyblock}
y = 2   
\end{pyblock}

% Desired : environments with an other option writing environment content in "filename.py"

\begin{pyverbatim}[write="filename.py"]
x = 1
\end{pyverbatim}

% at this step, the external file does not exist so the file is created and the content x=1 written to the file
\begin{pyverbatim}[write="filename.py"]
x = 1
\end{pyverbatim}

% at this step, filename.py exist, so y = 2 is added
\begin{pyblock}[write="filename.py"]
y = 2   
\end{pyblock}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I saw that Piton had been changed to Python, but the name of the package used is `Piton` :) https://www.ctan.org/pkg/piton

Comment: I will add such feature in `piton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of `piton` (v. 2.3 2024-01-06) provides a new key `write` with that functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot François ! Since the optional arguments of `pyblock` and `pycode` are those of `piton`, this key works like a charm together with `pyblock`, `pycode`, etc.